# pre_get_posts pagination not working

Tags: wp-query, pagination, pre-get-posts

I've been trying to fix my pagination on for category pages but am at a loss.
This is my pre_get_posts function for category pages.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( !is_admin() // Only target the front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // Targets the main query only
         && $q->is_category() // Only target category pages
    ) {
        $today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
        $q->set( 'post_type', array( 'research_article', 'events' ) );
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num date' );
        $q->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array( 
                'key' => 'wpcf-date_time',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE',
                ),
            array(
                'key'      => 'wpcf-date_time',
                'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            'relation' => 'OR',
        ) );
    }
});
```

Everything runs correctly EXCEPT it doesn't display 12 posts per page or include the pagination. I've tried including **the_posts_pagination()** on my category.php with no luck. Am I supposed to set a paged variable in this pre_get_posts function? If so, how?

My category.php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<div class="welcome">
    <h1><?php echo single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php echo category_description(); ?> 
</div>

<div class="site">
    <main id="primary" class="site-main two-col-index">
    
    <?php // Output custom query loop
     if ( have_posts() ) :
        $i = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>
                <div class="post-box">
                     .... 
                </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'post_box' ); ?>
            <?php endif; $i++; ?> 
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
        the_posts_pagination();
        ?>
        
    </main><!-- #main -->

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you using `WP_Query` or `query_posts` on your `category.php` template? Or is it a standard post loop? There's no code for `category.php` so it's not possible to tell

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Tom, I've added my category.php code. What's weird is, some category pages load totally fine with pagination working, while others don't.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the `category.php` template, only thing I can think of is that you didn't get multiple pages of results. `the_posts_pagination` only has output when there are multiple pages. You do not and should not add `paged` values in` `pre_get_posts`, pagination parameters are imo a dead end and not the solution/cause of your issue. However, you can test this by setting `posts_per_page` to 1 or 2

Comment: Note that I'm also assuming that your post meta values have valid dates that are formatted correctly to be recognised as dates and parsed correctly by the database

Comment: I ended up setting posts_per_page to 2 and removed `$q->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 )` from my code and the pagination is working as expected! Perhaps there was some issue between my Settings for Posts and the posts_per_page definition for category.php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `$q->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 )` in the pre-get-posts function, I use the Read Settings 'Blog pages show at most' and that seemed to clear things up.